# Нормально ли, что я буду прописывать пути именно так?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, хостинг, репозиторий

К примеру я верстаю...
Сделал главную страницу и помимо неё мне ещё нужно сделать доп. страницы. Я их делаю вот так:
Чтобы в адресной строке не было надписи index.html, я создаю для каждой страницы отдельную папку с названием игры к примеру. В каждую папку создаю по новому файлу index.html. Я соответственно пишу такой вот путь: страницы/страница-вторая/
index.html в конце не пишу т.к. будет некрасиво в строке. И из-за того, что я не пишу index.html в конце пути, я не могу перейти по этим ссылкам и соответственно не могу посмотреть как работает сам сайт т.к. я смогу посмотреть когда он уже будет залит на хостинг.
Для меня это не проблема, я могу спокойно глянуть весь сайт на localhost. Но если это заказ, то заказчик не сможет его проверить. Как тогда быть в такой ситуации?
Если пургу написал и непонятно, то не агритесь)

Comment: Показывать или нет index.html или index.php в адресной строке - настраивается, например в .htaccess, но на суть загрузки страниц это не влияет. Всё равно, если не указано другой странички в папке, то грузится именно index. Что значит нельзя перейти по таким ссылкам? Что значит, заказчик не сможет протестировать?

Comment: @Quazimorda Постараюсь объяснить и после этого комментария, я кину ссылку на имгур с двумя скринами и я думаю, что ты поймёшь)
Если я щас зайду в папку и открою index.html с помощью Chrome, то главная страница будет, но картинок не будет и если я перейду по какой-нибудь ссылке, то ничего не выйдет скажем. Но если я зайду на сайт через localhost, то всё ок (пути не меняю)

Comment: @Quazimorda https://imgur.com/a/D4L0WH2

Comment: Так вопрос в том как прописывать пути к картинкам, а не про название index.html. Почитайте про абсолютные и относительные адреса в html.